# Floating to the right

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I am designing a website using HTML and CSS and there appears to be an invisible margin somewhere.

Currently, my website looks like this:

```css
h1, h2 {
  font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  border: 5px solid #375E97;
}

article, aside {
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 1.5% 0;
  border: 5px solid #375E97;
  border-left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

article {
  width: 60%;
}

aside {
  width: 30%;
  background-image: url("money-stack.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 200px 200px;
}

h1 {
  background-color: #375E97;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 6.9vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 2.1% auto;
  line-height: 4.9vw;
  height: 5vw;
}

h2 {
  color: #375E97;
  font-size: 3.5vw;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1% 0 0 0;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

.sub-heading {
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}

.sub-heading > span {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Act 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous|Roboto:400,700,400i" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Filler text here</h1>
    </header>
    <article>
      <h2>More more</h2>
      <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts.</p>

<p>Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean.</p>

<p>A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.</p>

<p>It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.</p>

<p>Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar.</p>
    </article>
    <aside>
      <h2>And More</h2>
      <p>
        <div class="sub-heading">
          <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
        </div>
        <br>
        <p>The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen.</p>
      </p>
    </aside>
  </body>

</html>
```

If you look closely at the `article` and `aside` in the middle of the screenshot, you can see that I have made their `display: inline-block;` and removed the border from the left of the `aside` (smaller one).

### The Problem

The problem is that I want to actually "pin" the `aside` to the right of the body, not the article. I know that to make this work I would have to remove the border from the right and add it to the left.

### What I Have Tried

- Playing around with various values for align, text-align and all the other aligns you can think of.
- Making the `aside` and `article` have no tags in between them.

**Please note, I have seen other solutions for this, but I want a clean solution that makes sense.**

Comment: Can you provide any fiddle here.

Comment: try `float:left` on the `article` and `right` on the `aside`... can't do much with a minimal verifiable example...

Comment: The described behaviour you are trying to achieve is not what inline-elements are designed for. Use floats like kukkuz mentioned and use a clearfix for the surrounding container

Comment: Add fiddle please!

Comment: you sure it is not an invisible border? Can you provide jsfiddle with that specific example?

Comment: @KilianStinson Could you explain what a clearfix is? kukkuz float did work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you were trying to achieve I guess.
`article` and `aside` are now floated left and right.
This is actually the solution from kukkuz in the comments. I don't know why it shouldn't work for you.

A clearfix is used instead of an additional element with `clear: both`
Without the surrounding element, `body` in this case, doesn't get the height from its content and the border around everything wouldn't display correctly.

```css
h1, h2 {
  font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  border: 5px solid #375E97;
}

body:after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

article, aside {
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 1.5% 0;
  border: 5px solid #375E97;
  border-left: 0;
}

article {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
}

aside {
  width: 30%;
  border-left: 5px solid #375E97;
  border-right: 0;
  float: right;
  background-image: url("money-stack.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 200px 200px;
}

h1 {
  background-color: #375E97;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 6.9vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 2.1% auto;
  line-height: 4.9vw;
  height: 5vw;
}

h2 {
  color: #375E97;
  font-size: 3.5vw;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1% 0 0 0;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

.sub-heading {
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}

.sub-heading > span {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Act 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous|Roboto:400,700,400i" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Filler text here</h1>
    </header>
    <article>
      <h2>More more</h2>
      <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts.</p>

<p>Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean.</p>

<p>A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.</p>

<p>It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.</p>

<p>Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar.</p>
    </article>
    <aside>
      <h2>And More</h2>
      <p>
        <div class="sub-heading">
          <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
        </div>
        <br>
        <p>The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen.</p>
      </p>
    </aside>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your issue. There's many ways you could achieve this, the most obvious one would be to remove your inline rule and make both aside and article float: right; and float: left; respectively, but float was intended to make text float around images and not exactly to position divs (eventhough it works). As so, what I would try is to position: absolute; both the aside and article; and use left, right, top, bottom to position elements.

```css
article {
    position: absolute;
    top: 69px;
    width: 60%;
}

aside {
    background-image: url("money-stack.png");
    background-position: 200px 200px;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    top: 69px;
    width: 30%;
}

body {
    border: 5px solid #375e97;
    color: black;
    font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
    min-height: 318px;
}
```

After, you can either set a minimum size for the container, or add a clear:both; styled element to the bottom in order to make the container stretch to the correct size.

One other thing I think you should change is the fact that you're using body as your container and applying styles to it. I think it's good practice to create an actual container div, and apply styles to that instead.